# How can i add a ssl for the port 8080? In apache2 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, apache2, ssl, https, mod-ssl

I was trying to add my ssl certificate to port 8080 but when I enter via https it tells me this error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

This is my subdomain_maindomain.onlin.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName panel.example.online
  ServerAlias www.exmaple.online
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.online
    ServerName panel.example.online
    ServerAlias www.panel.example.online
    DocumentRoot /var/www/pufferpanel
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.online/example.online.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.online/example.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.online/example.online.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
```

towards

```
<VirtualHost *:443 *:8080>
```